# How to fix white background. Trying to make transparent navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I want to make a full-page landing with a transparent navbar using bootstrap4. I want a navbar that sticks to the top as you scroll down.

When I use the class 'fixed-top', it looks ok but doesn't follow as you scroll down. When I use 'sticky-top' it makes the background the navbar white.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
         <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler-1" aria-controls="navbarToggler-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
```

```css
.bg-dark{
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove this class ( bg-dark )  when its on sticky it can be done on thru js or if you want to use only css then you have to use body class with bg-dark like this  ( body .bg-dark{background:none;} header .bg-dark{background:none;}  ) you can also add there important if you want to add that.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 300) {
        $(".navbar").addClass("sticky_nav");
        $(".navbar").removeClass("bg-dark");
    } else {
        $(".navbar").removeClass("sticky_nav");
        $(".navbar").addClass("bg-dark");
    }
});
```

```css
.navbar.sticky_nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
         <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler-1" aria-controls="navbarToggler-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         </div>
  </nav>
  <div style="height:200px; width:100%; background:#f00; display:block;"></div>
   <div style="height:300px; width:100%; background:#000; display:block;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I made like this

html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

css

```
.navbar-fixed {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

js

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  console.log($(window).scrollTop())
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 63) {
    $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
  }
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 64) {
    $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
  }
});
```

Hope can help you

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar.bg-dark{
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.navbar.navbar-dark .navbar-brand{
color: #000}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
         <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler-1" aria-controls="navbarToggler-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar get background color from `bg-dark`

Just remove class `bg-dark` from `<nav class="">`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark sticky-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
         <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler-1" aria-controls="navbarToggler-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

> **Why? Need to remove bg-dark**
>
> Because `bg-dark` have this attribute
>
> ```
> .bg-dark {
>    background-color: #343a40 !important;
> }
> ```

Let's take **DEMO** here!

```html
<body style="background-color: gray;">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark sticky-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler-1" aria-controls="navbarToggler-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler-1">
      xxx
    </div>
  </nav>

  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/19/11/19/computer-1209641_960_720.jpg">
</body>
```